# How to configure Gitlab Runner to connect to Artifactory?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, gitlab, artifactory, gitlab-ci-runner

I am trying to set Gitlab runner to connect to Artifactory and pull images.My yml file to set RUnner looks like below :

gitlabUrl: https://gitlab.bayer.com/
runnerRegistrationToken: r*******-
rbac:
create: false
serviceAccountName: iz-sai-s
serviceAccount.name: iz-sai-s

runners:
privileged: true

resources:
limits:
memory: 32000Mi
cpu: 4000m
requests:
memory: 32000Mi
cpu: 2000m

What changes are needed to configure my runner properly to connect to Artifactory URL and pull images from there ?

Answer (score 2):

This is an example where my runner runs as docker container with an image having artifactory cli configured in it, so in your case your runner should have jfrog cli configured , next it needs an api key to access artifactory which you ll generate in artifactory and store in gitlab like below picture , exact path would be your repo - settings - CICD - variables

First it authenticates then uploads

```
publish_job:
  stage: publish_artifact
  image: xxxxxplan/jfrog-cli
  variables:
    ARTIFACTORY_BASE_URL: https://xxxxx.com/artifactory
    REPO_NAME:  my-rep
    ARTIFACT_NAME: my-artifact
  script:
    - jfrog rt c --url="$ARTIFACTORY_BASE_URL"/ --apikey="$ARTIFACTORY_KEY"
    - jfrog rt u "target/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar" "$REPO_NAME"/"$ARTIFACT_NAME"_"$CI_PIPELINE_ID.jar" --recursive=false
```

Mark the answer as accepted if it fulfils your requirement
Also make sure to use indentation in your question which is not there
[image]

Edit 1 : Adding the whole gitlab_ci.yml

```
stages:
  - build_unittest
  - static_code_review
  - publish_artifact
  
  
image: maven:3.6.1-jdk-8-alpine
cache:
  paths:
    - .m2/repository
    - target/
variables:
  MAVEN_OPTS: "-Dmaven.repo.local=.m2/repository"

build_unittest_job:
  stage: build_unittest
  script: 'mvn clean install'
  tags:
    - my-docker 
  artifacts:
    paths:
    - target/*.jar
    expire_in: 20 minutes
  when: manual  
code_review_job:
  stage: static_code_review
  variables:
    SONARQUBE_BASE_URL: https://xxxxxx.com
  script:
    - mvn sonar:sonar -Dsonar.projectKey=xxxxxx -Dsonar.host.url=https://xxxxx -Dsonar.login=xxxxx
  
  tags:
    - my-docker
  cache:
    paths:
      - /root/.sonar/cache
      - target/
      - .m2/repository
  when: manual    
publish_job:
  stage: publish_artifact
  image: plan/jfrog-cli
  variables:
    ARTIFACTORY_BASE_URL: https://xxxx/artifactory
    REPO_NAME:  maven
    ARTIFACT_NAME: myart
  script:
    - jfrog rt c --url="$ARTIFACTORY_BASE_URL"/ --apikey="$ARTIFACTORY_KEY"
    - jfrog rt u "target/demo-SNAPSHOT.jar" "$REPO_NAME"/"$ARTIFACT_NAME"_"$CI_PIPELINE_ID.jar" --recursive=false
  tags:
    - my-docker
  when: manual
```

Comment: Should this be included in the runner file values.yml or confirlg.timl which u am running through helm or in the gitlab-ci.yml file ?

Comment: I have pasted my gitlab_ci.yml , I can give you the whole ci.yml if,your context is not clear to me

Comment: Yes please give me the file as I am doing it first time so I am myself very confused about all of these.

Comment: edited the answer , also your question is very broad , you can start working and break it into small parts

Comment: Thanks. I am able to pull the image from docker hub and push to private repo. Now the task is to pull the base image from private repo ? Any ide a?

Comment: if you pull or push to a private repo u have to provide the credentials , u can store that in same place as API KEY

Comment: I am able to push but not pull

Comment: I cant answer this without looking at logs or errors

Comment: ERROR: Job failed (system failure): prepare environment: waiting for pod running: pulling image "artifactory.bayer.com/artifactory/aie-docker-dev-mydockerrepo:latest": image pull failed: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: unauthorized.

I am getting this error and calling image like below through gitlab-ci.yml file 

image: artifactory.bayer.com/artifactory/aie-docker-dev-mydockerrepo:latest

Comment: paste ur gitlab_ci and post in which line u r getting error

Comment: Yes I am sharing with you the link for another question I asked : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68271221/how-to-pull-base-image-from-private-artifactory?noredirect=1#comment120661042_68271221 

plrease go through this as i have posted all the details there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234587/discussion-between-aiyaz-and-thatguy).