# How to pull base image from private artifactory?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, gitlab, artifactory

The task is to pull base image from private artifactory repo rather than docker hub due to rate limiting issue.

In the `gitlab-ci.yml` file I have mentioned base image like

```
image: artifactory.***.com/artifactory/aie-docker-dev-mydockerrepo:latest
```

But I am getting unauthorized error which might be because to pull this image I am still not logged into the repo.

My error :

```
WARNING: Failed to pull image with policy "": image pull failed: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: unauthorized
```

My question is Am I specifying the correct way to mention image? And where should I try to login in the gitlab file to pull the base image from Artifactory rather than docker hub.

P.S currently I am able to pull image from docker hub and pushing it to my private repository so credentials are working fine.

My gitlab file

```
image: artifactory.bayer.com/artifactory/aie-docker-dev-mydockerrepo:latest

services:  
 
  - name: docker:18.09.7-dind  
    entrypoint: ["env", "-u", "DOCKER_HOST"]  
    command: ["dockerd-entrypoint.sh"]  
  
variables:  
  DOCKER_AUTH_CONFIG: $DOCKER_AUTH_CONFIG

  DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2
  DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: ""
  Task: build
  Repo: iz-sai-eu
  Tag: latest
  Country: test


before_script:
  - apk --no-cache add curl
  - apk --no-cache add bash
  - docker login $ARTIFACTORY_URL -u $QA_ARTIFACTORY_USER -p $QA_ARTIFACTORY_ACCESS_TOKEN

stages:
  - build
  - tag-dev
  - deploy-qa

build:
  stage: build
  only:
    - Artifactory_Test
    - merge_requests
  tags:
    - arte
  script:
    - echo 'in build stage'
    - source scripts/dev_build.sh

  allow_failure: false
```

Comment: have you made sure `$DOCKER_AUTH_CONFIG` contain valid docker credentials? can you paste that content(do some necessary obsfucation)?

Comment: => `docker login artifactory.bayer.com` then launch your build. If this is an automated build from gitlab, set protected vars containing the login and password and issue => `echo "${YOUR_CI_DOCKER_PASSWORD}" | docker login -u "${YOUR_CI_DOCKER_LOGIN}"  --password-stdin artifactory.bayer.com"`. A good practice is to `docker logout artifactory.bayer.com` once you are done.

Comment: The login credentials are correct as I have used them to push image from docker hub to artifactory. Now when I put the image first with artifactory address it first tries to login I think. So where should I put my login command so that it logins first and then pull image from artifactory repository.please point the part in gitlab-ci file

Comment: I read your gitlab-ci script a bit fast prior to making my first comment.... Do you have any evidence of a successful login in your ci log just before `echo 'in build stage'`? Are you able to pull anything else on a public repo? As a debug step, did you try to put the login command directly in `script:` in the build task?

Comment: Yes for successful login evidence I have already pulled image from docker hub and configure login in dev_build file and able to login and push image. So login thing is confirmed. Also I added login in before_script section as can be seen in the question but still getting Samee error. Where should I put the login in the above file so that it login first and then pull the image from repository

Comment: DO I need docker installed on my local to configure DOCKER_AUTH_CONFIG ? I am using Gitlab runner. If I dont have docker installed on my local, will this work ? I am running the processes through gitlab so havent installed docker in my local